How to show 'View, Edit, Delete' button based on specific condition while using Yajra Laravel Datatables?
In my Laravel 10.x application, I am using Yajra-Laravel Datatable ajax version. I wanted to hide or show action buttons based on applications specific requirements. Like for example if a leave application is already approved, then I wanted to hide the 'Edit' button from the list of all leaves.
I see all the buttons are available in: resources/views/partials/datatablesActions.blade.php file like below:
@can($viewGate)
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.' . $crudRoutePart . '.show', $row->id) }}">
        {{ trans('global.view') }}
    </a>
@endcan
@can($editGate)
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{ route('admin.' . $crudRoutePart . '.edit', $row->id) }}">
        {{ trans('global.edit') }}
    </a>
@endcan
@can($deleteGate)
    <form action="{{ route('admin.' . $crudRoutePart . '.destroy', $row->id) }}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('{{ trans('global.areYouSure') }}');" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="{{ trans('global.delete') }}">
    </form>
@endcan

In controller I have the following:
$table->editColumn('actions', function ($row) {
    $viewGate = 'leave_show';
    $editGate = 'leave_edit';
    $deleteGate = 'leave_delete';
    $crudRoutePart = 'leaves';

    return view('partials.datatablesActions', compact(
        'viewGate',
        'editGate',
        'deleteGate',
        'crudRoutePart',
        'row'
    ));
});

Can someone help me, how can I pass some logic to show / hide specific buttons based on requirements?

To include a status condition, such as approved or not approved, in $row, we can set a condition in the view template as shown below:
@can($editGate)
    @unless($row->status === 'approved')
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{ route('admin.' . $crudRoutePart . '.edit', $row->id) }}">
            {{ trans('global.edit') }}
        </a>
    @endunless
@endcan

